# using greek letters as variable names

Tags: input, unicode, spyder

How would I enter greek letters to be used e.g. as variable names in Python 3 under Spyder? Currently I'm using the following Python code on the console:

```py
s = '\u03B1'
print(s)
```

`α` is printed on the console and I can copy it into my source. I was wondering if there is a way to directly enter it into my console, perhaps even some macro that automatically replaces `\alpha` with `α`.

Comment: I would suggest use their English names. Like alpha for `α` It is recommended in the PEPE 3131 anyways. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/#policy-specification
PEP 8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#ascii-compatibility

Comment: @Mark I don't get what you're trying to say

Comment: @Goion  Yes, that's the way I've always done things but sometimes it would be cleaner to program the equations exactly as they are

Comment: That is subjective. I would rather write `alpha` over `α`. There is no key for `α` on my keyboard.

Comment: @Nachiket you are asking how to use greek letters as variable names. I'm suggesting you can just use them: `π = 3.14` <-- that works in python (although I'm with Goion on questioning the wisdom of doing so.)

Comment: What mark is saying that you can copy paste `α` into your terminal. It should work. Just like ASCII characters.

Comment: "I was wondering if there is a way to directly enter it into my console" sure the same way you directly enter *anything*. This isn't a python question, really. You need to figure out how to configure your keyboard to input the characters you want.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good point. I was only thinking of Spyder.

Comment: @Goion Yes, I know I can cut and paste. That's what I said in my post. Mighty inconvenient though. I was looking for a method which would automatically replace \alpha with the symbol alpha.

Comment: Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254477/linux-alternative-to-altnumpad-codes or https://superuser.com/questions/1024763/how-can-i-find-the-alt-keycode-for-a-glyph-with-the-windows-system-tools

Comment: If stuck with copy and paste, add this comment to your code: `#ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρσςτυφχψωάέήϊίόύϋώΆΈΉΊΌΎΏ±≥≤ΪΫ÷≈°√ⁿ²`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Spyder IPython console, typing `\alpha` followed by a tab gives you `α`. You can then copy paste it into the Python editor. I am searching for a better solution.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This the only possible solution for the moment (June 2022).